# Nombre del archivo: núcleo / model.php

Tags: codeigniter

Estoy aprendiendo a utilizar codeigniter 3.1.3, siguiendo un tutorial en vídeos; me he encontrado con el siguiente inconveniente:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Test::$db
>
> Filename: core/Model.php
>
> Line Number: 77
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/claudio/www/ci_cms/application/models/Test_model.php Line:
>   28 Function: __get
>
> File: /home/claudio/www/ci_cms/application/controllers/Test.php Line:
>   28 Function: registro
>
> File: /home/claudio/www/ci_cms/index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once
>
> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to a member function get() on null
>
> Filename: /home/claudio/www/ci_cms/application/models/Test_model.php
>
> Line Number: 28
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/claudio/www/ci_cms/application/controllers/Test.php Line:
>   28 Function: registro
>
> File: /home/claudio/www/ci_cms/index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

**Controlador Test.php**

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        echo 'Index Test...';
    }

    public function metodo2($var1, $var2) {
        //$this->load->database();
        //echo '<pre>';
        //print_r($this->db->select(['id', 'direccion'])->get('test')-    >result_array());
        //return;

        $this->load->model('test_model', 't_model');
        //echo '<pre>';
        print_r($this->t_model->registro());
        $this->load->view('test/test', ['titulo' => 'Titulo de Test']);
    }

}
```

**Modelo Test_model.php**

```
class Test_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function registro($select = null, $where = null, $fetch = null) {
        if (is_array($select)) {
            $this->db->select($select);
        }

        if (is_array($where)) {
            $this->db->where($where);
        }

        if ($fetch == 'object') {
            $this->db->get('test')->result();
        }
        $this->db->get('test')->result_array();
    }

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por favor revisa [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78)

Comment: Ya configuraste el archivo `config/database.php` con los datos de conexión? Al igual te falta leer dicha libreria `$this->load->library('database');` esto lo realizas en el model o en el arachivo `config/autoload.php`

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje es porque no has iniciado la conexión a la base de datos, prueba agregar la linea `$this->load->database();` al inicio del método `registro()` del modelo y se soluciona:

```
class Test_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function registro($select = null, $where = null, $fetch = null) {
        $this->load->database();

        if (is_array($select)) {
            $this->db->select($select);
        }

        if (is_array($where)) {
            $this->db->where($where);
        }

        if ($fetch == 'object') {
            $this->db->get('test')->result();
        }
        $this->db->get('test')->result_array();
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar con más detalle cómo es que esto responde a la pregunta? Quizás agregando un fragmento de código más sustancial y una breve explicación ayudaría a cualquiera que les está respuesta en el futuro. La idea del sitio es agregar contenido con la mayor calidad posible

Comment: Por favor lee **[cómo escribo una buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**. Una vez que tengas 50 puntos de reputación podrás [hacer comentarios](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).